# Customized cursor - replace the existing mouse-pointer to a Static image

Tags: visualforce, css, mousehover

[image]I want to create a customized cursor that will replace the existing mouse-pointer to a Static image that I have uploaded in the Static Resource.
I tried doing it with a simple CSS as below:

```
<apex:page >
    <style>
        #homewrapper
        {
            cursor: url('!$Resource.CursorBee'), auto;
        }
    </style>

   <div id="homewrapper">
        <p><b>Coming Soon</b></p>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

When I point the mouse over `<p><b>Coming Soon</b></p>` it does not change to the bee image.
However, if I write `<apex:image url="{!$Resource.CursorBee}" width="50" height="50"/>` in the apex page body, it shows fine.

Please, let me know how may I change my mouse-pointer to a Static image.

Comment: @Guy: I tried as per the thread you provided. But it didn't work. 
Here is what I did:
Zipped my cursor file **cursorbee.cur** and made a **MyResource.zip** file. Uploaded the zip file as static resource. Finally wrote the code : 

`cursor: url({!URLFOR($Resource.MyResource,'images/')}cursorbee.cur);`

Please advice...

Comment: did you put it in an 'images' folder before zipping? (and did you zip the folder along?)

Comment: No, the folder name was MyResource. Now its working fine. 
Thanks for the reference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked perfectly for me:

```
<apex:page>
    <style>
        #homewrapper
        {
            cursor: url({!URLFOR($Resource.MyResource,'MyResource/')}cursorbee.cur), auto;
        }
    </style> <body  id="homewrapper">    <div id="homewrapper">
        <p><b>Coming Soon..</b></p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.MyResource, 'MyResource/cursorbee1.png')}" /> </body>     </apex:page>
```